# HTML5 multiple file uploads on iOS

Tags: html, upload, ios-camera

I have an HTML5 form that has three file fields which the user can click on to take a photo with the camera or select an existing photo from the device.

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" id="file">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file2" id="file2">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file3" id="file3">`

When taking or selecting a photo on Android the file name is the actual file name on the device. However, when selecting or taking a photo on iOS, it is automatically given a name of Photo1. This happens for all three fields which does not work for me because our backend needs different names for each photo.

Looking for a way to override this Photo1 and specifiy a different name instead of Photo1 ?